# Find the probability of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability

X, Y are both random variables of uniform distribution, $0\le\ X \le\ 3$, $0\le\ Y \le\ 4$, then what is the probability of $X \lt Y$?

Comment: Are the variables independent?

Comment: @ncmathsadist Yes, they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left.\int_{0}^{3}{{\rm d}X \over 3}\int_{0}^{4}{{\rm d}Y \over 4}\right\vert
_{X < Y}
=
{1 \over 12}
\int_{0}^{3}{\rm d}X\int_{X}^{4}{\rm d}Y = \color{#ff0000}{\large{5 \over 8}}
=
\overbrace{\quad{3\times 1 + \left(3\times 3\right)/2 \over 12}\quad}
^{\it\mbox{by drawing a picture}}
$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! But can you post the picture you drew. I have difficulty visualize it.

Comment: @JamesLee Done.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a 3-by-4 rectangle in the plane.  Shade in the region where $x<y$.  What percentage of the rectangle is shaded?

Comment: Simple and good.

Comment: It's wrong. The correct answer is 5/8. You are calculating the probability of Y greater than 3. But for example Y can be 3, X can be 2. Then it is not the case

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it's wrong". As you can see illustrated in Felix Marin's answer, $\frac{5}{8}$ of the rectangle will be shaded.